# Angularjs output time only in php from html input time attribute

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I want to save from HTML to PHP via Angularjs the value of "time" attribute.

In my HTML i have :

```
<input type="time" ng:model="stime.val" ng:value="stime.val | date: 'HH:mm:ss'" >
```

In the controller :

```
$scope.stime = { val: new Date(1970, 0, 1, 09, 00, 00) };
$scope.sendtime = [{ 'time'  : $scope.stime }];
http({ method: 'POST', url: '../index.php',
       data : $.param({ 'sendTime' : $scope.sendtime, 
                        'type' : 'post_time'
                }),
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success( cut off code...
```

In PHP :

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
$postResponse = file_get_contents("php://input");
json_decode($postResponse);
if($_POST['type'] == 'post_time')
    { 
       $startTime = $_POST['sendTime']['val']; 
       print_r($startTime); 
    }
```

The returned data is ( let's say i input "15:06:04" )

```
Tue Dec 01 2015 15:06:04 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

My Question is, how can i make it to return just the time from HTML?

Something like this..

```
15:06:04
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same filter in the controller in this way:

```
console.log( $filter('date')( $scope.stime.val, 'HH:mm:ss' ) );
```

Comment: I have tired this way but i still receive the same output as 
Thu Jan 01 1970 09:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) any idea? Thanks

Comment: Ah ok, you have the Date object inside stime, I updated my answer. I tested it and it works correctly